# How do canards reduce the X-59's sonic boom?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, supersonic, canard, sonic-boom

[X-59](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_X-59_Quesst)

> As of 2017, the ground noise was expected to be around 60 dB(A), about 1/1000 as loud as current supersonic aircraft. This was to be achieved by using a long, narrow airframe and canards to keep the shock waves from coalescing.

I fail to see the relevance of the canards. How are they supposed to reduce the boom?

Answer (score 9):

One of the important factors for sonic booms is the longitudinal distribution of lift along the aircraft.  The canard helps bring some of that lift very far forward.

Notice also that the aircraft has two horizontal tails – the large one in plane with the wing and another smaller one at the top of the vertical tail.  These work to distribute the lift – and thereby the pressure signature – in a tailored way.

Comment: I assume the oddly flat nose is for a similar purpose?

Answer (score -2):

The X59 has not flown yet, so there's no confirmed guarantee it will successfully yield a quieter plane. Despite its talk about “quiet” SSTs, Boom is lobbying and [affecting legislation that would exempt these and other jets from new stringent noise standards.](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/11/opinion/reviving-supersonic-jets-will-damage-the-climate.html)

Comment: The question is specifically about the canards and how they would interact with shockwave intensity.